# Join with case statement using dynamic values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a brain fart and could use some help. I hope my description of the issue is concise and clear enough.

Let's say I have an auto shop and I have contracts with insurance companies to repair vehicles at certain costs. These costs are based on the insurance company, the technician performing the job, and the job type. The contracts are a little weird, however. Only certain technicians have special rates for specific jobs.

For example: a contract with company 'A' states that they will pay $XX for a motor replacement if Sally replaces it, but they will pay $YY dollars if it's anyone else.

Now, I am trying to estimate the cash flow of my company, so I want to calculate the expected payments based on the mentioned criteria above. Let's pretend I have a table (jobs) that contains the job information, and this table contains fields for the job_type_id, technician_id, and insurance_id. There is another table (payment_schedule). This table also contains job_type_id, technician_id, and insurance_id. If there is no technician specified (eg: anyone but Sally), then the technician_id is 0.

In the case that Sally (technician_id = 26) is the only one with special rates for all of the insurance companies, then it's fairly easy for me to create a join condition:

```
select 
  * 
from jobs as j 
  join payment_schedule as s on s.insurance_id = j.insurance_id 
    and j.job_type_id = s.job_type_id 
    and s.technician_id = case when j.technician_id = 26 then j.technician_id else 0 end
```

However, reality is more complicated than that. Sally may be the only one at that particular location with special prices, but we have multiple locations with many technicians. These contracts change frequently, so I need to be able to create a case statement that checks the id 'dynamically'. I tried this, knowing it'd probably be slow. It is.

```
select 
  * 
from jobs as j 
  join payment_schedule as s on s.insurance_id = j.insurance_id 
    and j.job_type_id = s.job_type_id 
    and s.technician_id = case when j.technician_id in (select distinct technician_id from payment_schedule) then j.technician_id else 0 end
```

It's definitely slow, and I'm not surprised, but I'm having trouble coming up with a good way of ensuring we don't get multiple payment_schedule records for each job record (1 to 1 relationship) without having to hard code IDs into a case statement. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

I feel like I'm missing something wildly obvious: I've been staring at this for too long and need fresh eyes. Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Ярослав Машко  I'm having trouble coming up with a good way of ensuring we don't get multiple payment_schedule records for each job record (1 to 1 relationship) without having to hard code IDs into a case statement. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?  I'm having trouble coming up with a good way of ensuring we don't get multiple payment_schedule records for each job record (1 to 1 relationship) without having to hard code IDs into a case statement. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Can you join to the distinct as a subquery and isnull replace to 0?

Comment: Please try to provide sample data, expected output and anything else related.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like below but if you give some data and desired output will help

```
select 
  * 
from jobs as j 
  join payment_schedule as s on s.insurance_id = j.insurance_id 
            and j.job_type_id = s.job_type_id 
            and 1 = case when j.technician_id = s.technician_id then 1 else 0 end
```